# in WEB-INF folder, is index.jsp always necessary when using servlets only?

Tags: java, servlets

I read somewhere that WEB-INF consists of web.xml, classes, lib and index.jsp . I am using servlets. I want to know if it is necessary to include index.jsp in WEB-INF .If yes, then why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not necessary to include index.jsp in web-inf folder

Comment: `index.jsp` is usually not inside of `WEB-INF` anyway. Anything inside of `WEB-INF` is not web-accessible directly.

Comment: where did you read that?

Comment: Did my answer help you @XYZ?